# Should imports be duplicated in doctests?

Tags: python, import, doctest

I have a doctest that requires multiple imports. The imports are already in the global scope of the module, so the doctest can pass without the imports being specified within the doctest. But is it better practise to include the imports within the doctest itself so that the code snippet in the doctest truly stands alone? Are there any practical differences?

E.g. this works:

```
import math

def f():
    """
    >>> math.factorial(2)
    2
    """

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Or should I also add the import like:

```
def f():
    """
    >>> import math
    >>> math.factorial(2)
    2
    """
```

Comment: I would defer to numpy's practices. They do not import in the doctests. See https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/92ebe1e9a6aeb47a881a1226b08218175776f9ea/numpy/core/numeric.py#L119-L134

Comment: @jakub Thanks, but numpy sometime to include imports e.g. https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/92ebe1e9a6aeb47a881a1226b08218175776f9ea/numpy/core/numeric.py#L1884-L1889 -- perhaps the `import`ant point is whether the import is used many times or only in the doctest